# FFmpeg converting from video to audio missing duration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ffmpeg

I'm attempting to load YouTube videos via their direct video URL (retrieved using [ytdl-core](https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core)). I load them using the `request` library. I then pipe the result to a stream, which is used as the input to ffmpeg (via [fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg)). The code looks something like this:

```
var getAudioStream = function(req, res) {
    var requestUrl = 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=' + req.params.videoId;
    var audioStream = new PassThrough();
    var videoUrl;

    ytdl.getInfo(requestUrl, { downloadURL: true }, function(err, info) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/x-wav');
      res.setHeader('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
      videoUrl = info.formats ? info.formats[0].url : '';
      request(videoUrl).pipe(audioStream);

      ffmpeg()
        .input(audioStream)
        .outputOptions('-map_metadata 0')
        .format('wav')
        .pipe(res);
    });
  };
```

This actually works just fine, and the frontend successfully receives just the audio in WAV format and is playable. However, the audio is missing any information about its size or duration (and all other metadata). This also makes it unseekable.

I'm assuming this is lost somewhere during the `ffmpeg` stage, because if I load the video directly via the URL passed to `request` it loads and plays fine, and has a set duration/is seekable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to know the output size nor duration until it is finished.  FFmpeg cannot know this information ahead of time in most cases.  Even if it could, the way you are executing FFmpeg it prevents you from accessing the extra information.

Besides, to support seeking you need to support range requests.  This isn't possible either, short of encoding the file up to the byte requested and streaming from there on.

Basically, this isn't possible by the nature of what you're doing.

Comment: Is it possible to hardcode the duration then, if I know it through other methods?

Comment: @Jakemmarsh You know the sample-accurate length of the output file you'll end up with?  How?  If you know this information, then it's possible for you to write your own muxer to handle the RIFF/WAVE chunks.  https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/  You could then request raw PCM samples from FFmpeg and pack them in the WAVE file yourself.

Comment: Since I'm getting the video from YouTube via ytdl, I'm given the duration beforehand represented in seconds. Unless I'm misunderstanding what I'd need to achieve this?

Comment: @Jakemmarsh The duration in seconds isn't accurate, it's an approximation.  The playback time of that video will vary slightly when pulled out of the original form and converted to raw PCM samples.  Once that is done, you'll find that duration in seconds wouldn't be nearly accurate enough anyway.  For CD-quality audio, there are 44,100 samples per second.  Accurately encoding the WAVE headers requires that you know how long your file is exactly, not approximately.  Being off by 20,000 samples isn't accurate, unless you don't mind generating broken files.